# XPATH to select all elements with same attribute name but different values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Actually i want construct an XPATH to click on all emails one by one. I see that there is an attribute "date-time" in all email divs. How i can find the XPATH of elements with attribute "date-time" given that all values are different for this attribute.

of one email [image: emails i want o select one by one]:

```
 <div tabindex="-1" data- 
 convid="AQQkADAwATYwMAItZmQxOC0yZDI2LTAwAi0wMAoAEAA4dP/BjTqlQb/qmiKQpP+f" 
 data-time="2018-05-01T11:14:04+08:00" id="_ariaId_401" class=""><div> 
 </div><div autoid="_lvv_d" class="_lvv_H1 _lvv_I1 _lvv_L1 
 listItemDefaultBackground" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria- 
 haspopup="true"> 
 <div class="_lvv_M1 ms-bgc-ts
```

all other identifiers look very dynamic which changes frequently as page is refreshed. Can you please help find XPATH of "date-time" to select all emails.

Here is what i have trying so far -

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[text()[contains(.,'data-time')]])
```

Comment: Hi, why do you want to add constraints to the xpath ? If you anyway want to select all the emails ?

Comment: Update the question with the _HTML_ of some more _email_ elements

Answer (score 1):

You can locate by attribute without value

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-time]')
```

Comment: @user3121891 You need to give more details. Any exceptions? doesn't give the expected results? something else?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML shared by you contains **id** as  _ariaId_401.

This ID is dynamic but some part of this ID (ariaId) is static [I'm assuming].

you can try out this **code** :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id,'ariaId')]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check by using below xpath,

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@autoid,'_lvv') and @aria-haspopup='true']');
```